Unable to access application running in docker container using localhost or 127.0.0.1 in WSL2
Windows 11 dev environment on Ubuntu. Attempting to use an application running on a Docker container using localhost:8080 fails:
curl localhost:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

However, I am able to get a payload if I use my the IP address that's returned by ipconfig in PowerShell:
curl 192.168.0.241:8080
{"uptime":1145.711749106,"message":"OK","timestamp":1720939890098}

The curl commands above were run in WSL.
The hostnames of my Linux and WSL machines are the same. If I run the curl command using my hostname in bash, it fails, but it succeeds in PowerShell:
curl <hostname>:8080

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
...

This application is working fine on my other PC, which is also Windows 11 running WSL2.
Additional information:
docker ps
<container_id>   <image_name>            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                           <container_name>

/etc/hosts
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       <linux_hostname>.        <linux_hostname>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

How can I troubleshoot this further?
